# How to deal with OpenVPN subnet collission?

Tags: networking, openvpn, subnet

My home subnet is 192.168.0.0/24 and very annoyingly *cannot* be changed at present.

I want to connect from remote networks via OpenVPN but obviously frequently find myself on subnets that have provisioned existing IPs and therefore we get a clash.

I understand it's possible to change the routing rules so that when I'm connecting remotely, certain IPs always resolve to my home network rather than the remote network I'm currently on. I understand this will make the clients on the remote network inaccessible.

[image]

**How do I do this using the OpenVPN admin GUI?**

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/1015091/569990

Comment: @Tom Yan: How do I do this using the OpenVPN admin GUI ?